# SQL Query SELECT Count & Sum from a table that uses another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the sum and count of a specific column in A while using B which is another table where `B.CheckerID IS NOT NULL AND A.DBDivRecID='3485'` ,

so it will get the sum and count in A where `B.CheckerID IS NOT NULL A.DBDivRecID='3485'`

I did this, but I am getting the results of both Table A and B combined, I found out that the DBShares column for both the tables are named the same,**I only want Table A's total DBShares, only need Table B for the checking of the CheckerID**

```
SELECT SUM(A.DBShares) As totalshares,COUNT(*) As totalcounts 
FROM ShrDivBenf As A 
INNER JOIN TEMPDRP_3485 AS B ON A.DBDivRecID=B.DBDivRecID 
WHERE B.CheckerID IS NOT NULL AND A.DBDivRecID='3485'
```

I want something like this (**WHERE CheckerID in Table B is not null**)

```
SELECT SUM(A.DBShares) As totalshares,COUNT(*) As totalcounts 
FROM ShrDivBenf As A 
WHERE CheckerID IS NOT NULL
```

Sample

Table A

```
+------------+----------+-------+
| DBDivRecID | DBShares |Name   |
+------------+----------+-------+
|       3485 |     5000 |John   |
|       3485 |     6000 |Mary   |
|       3485 |     7000 |Sam    |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

Table B

```
+------------+-----------+----------+--------+
| DBDivRecID | CheckerID | DBShares | DBName |
+------------+-----------+----------+--------+
|       3485 |      4555 |     5000 | John   |
|       3485 |      4555 |     6000 | Mary   |
|       3485 |      4555 |     7000 | Sam    |
|       3485 |      NULL |     8000 | Derek  |
+------------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Lets say if I do this

```
SELECT A.DbName, A.DbShares 
FROM ShrDivBenf As A 
INNER JOIN TEMPDRP_3485 AS B ON A.DBDivRecID=B.DBDivRecID 
WHERE B.CheckerID IS NOT NULL AND A.DBDivRecID='3485'
```

I will get this( It repeats the whole thing even though my database only has 1 John, Mary and Sam)

```
+----------+----------+
| DbName   | DBShares |
+----------+----------+
|  John    |     5000 |
|  Mary    |     6000 |
|  Sam     |     7000 |
|  John    |     5000 |
|  Mary    |     6000 |
|  Sam     |     7000 |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: What is not working correctly? Is the sum too large, and the count is too high (implying you are joining on too few columns, and getting duplicates) or is there a different issue?

Comment: Can you see the sum for Select count(*) from ShrDivBenf As A where A.DBDivRecID='3485'? Is this lower than the count yo get from the join?

Comment: Your query is fine. Please print the output. I think you will find out the output is not what you are presenting above.

Comment: yes, it is half of what i get from the join

Comment: @DerekToh . . . Edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Do note that if there are m matches in A and n matches in B you will get m*n entries in the resulting inner join.. are you sure that's what you're looking for? might be better if you include sample input/output

Comment: I think I used Inner join wrongly.. I only want the results from A while using B

Answer (score 0):

Since you have several rows with the same `DBDivRecID`, you're getting a Cartesian product when you join. One way to avoid this is to replace the `join` with an `in` operator:

```
SELECT SUM(A.DBShares) As totalshares, COUNT(*) As totalcounts 
FROM   ShrDivBenf
WHERE  DBDivRecID='3485' AND
       DBDivRecID IN (SELECT DBDivRecID 
                      FROM   TEMPDRP_3485
                      WHERE  CheckerID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this but I found out that even those with CheckerID IS NULL also has DBDivRecID = '3485'

Comment: @DerekToh I don't understand what you're trying to say. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: I edited table B, is there anyway I can directly get the CheckerID?

Comment: @DerekToh Can you please edit the question with the output you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want; You're looking for records where there is no null checker. Given that, try the following:

```
SELECT SUM(A.DBShares) As totalshares, COUNT(*) As totalcounts 
FROM   ShrDivBenf
WHERE  DBDivRecID='3485' AND
   DBDivRecID NOT IN (SELECT DBDivRecID 
                  FROM   TEMPDRP_3485
                  WHERE  CheckerID IS NULL)
```